# Code signing certificate not working when deployed by GPO

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, certificate

Our codesigning certificat from Symantec has been converted to a password protected  pfx with complete certificate chain, public- and private-key

Signing with signtool (version 10.0.17763.0, x64) works when the certificate is manually imported to a build server (Windows Server 2012 R2) but not when it is pushed with a GPO from DC (Server 2012 R2)

In both scenarios:

- The complete certificate chain is imported and all certificate
  details on DC is identical to the certificate on the server
- Certificate general tab on the server claims that 'You have a private
  key that corresponds to this certificate'

My signing command is this:

C:\Users\myUser>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x64\signtool.exe" sign /debug /v /a /sm /s Root /n "" /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll MyApp.exe

Result when executed after manual import to server:

```
After EKU filter, 40 certs were left.
After expiry filter, 34 certs were left.
After Subject Name filter, 1 certs were left.
After Private Key filter, 1 certs were left.
```

Result when executed after GPO push to server:

```
After EKU filter, 40 certs were left.
After expiry filter, 34 certs were left.
After Subject Name filter, 1 certs were left.
After Private Key filter, 0 certs were left.
SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.
```

What is the reason for **After Private Key filter, 0 certs were left** ?

Comment: You cannot use GPO to distribute certificates with private keys. Only public parts of the certificate can be deployed via GPO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My gpo for publishing certificates was setup with the certificate in: Computer Configuration, Policies, Windows Settings, Security Settings, Public Key Policies, Trusted Root certificates

To get it to work I also had to setup the same certificate in: Computer Configuration, Policies, Windows Settings, Security Settings, Public Key Policies, **Trusted Publishers**

I also had to enable Computer Configuration, Policies, Administrative Templates, Windows Components, Windows Update, **Allow signed updates from an intranet Microsoft update service location**

Comment: Did you need to specify a different certificate store parameter to use Trusted Publishers? e.g. iirc the root authority store is "/sm /s My"

Comment: No we used the same parameters